# How do I get values from string and then convert these values to different time zone?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

Data format as follows:

```
2019 12 18 18 15 05     TIMESTAMP
2019 12 18 23 15 05     TIMESTAMP
```

These values in strings are respectively year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. I try to write `awk` script. I could extract these values, not converting ISO 8601 date format (UTC) to UTC+02:00.

What I tried:

```bsh
awk '/TIMESTAMP/ {print strftime("%FT%T", mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" " $5" "$6))}'
```

```
2019-12-18T18:15:05 # UTC
2019-12-18T23:15:05 # UTC
```

Desired output using `awk`:

```
2019-12-18T20:15:05 # UTC+02:00:00
2019-12-19T01:15:05 # UTC+02:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved thanks to @steeldriver

`awk '/TIMESTAMP/ {print strftime("%FT%T",(2*3600) + mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" " $5" "$6))}'`